# Swiftにてグレースケール画像で任意のX,Y座標の白黒の濃度の値(0~255)を抽出したい

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Swiftにて白黒濃淡画像（グレースケール画像です）から指定されます任意のX,Y座標の白黒の濃度の値(0~255)を抽出したいと思っています。
どこか良いサイト等ございますでしょうか。
特に画像処理の知識等を当方持ちあわせておりません。皆様のお力添えをいただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageからピクセルの情報にアクセスすればよいので

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146557/how-do-i-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-a-uiimage-with-swift

の回答がよさそうに見えます。CGImageに変換したのち、UnsafePointerでごりごりアクセスする形になりそうです。

## 追加（グレースケール）

次の情報が良さそうです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768739/how-to-detect-image-is-grayscale

> CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents returns 1: This image is grayscale, finished (one exception: It could be alpha-only, but I doubt you'll be sending any images like that. If you are, there is a way to determine whether an image is alpha only through its CGAlphaInfo)
>
> CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents returns 3: This image is RGB, and further analysis is needed to determine if it is grayscale or not (as the other answer states, loop over the pixels and if you find one where !(R == G == B) then it is not grayscale.
>
> CGColorSpaceGetModel will return values like kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome or kCGColorSpaceModelRGB. This will take the ambiguity out of the above. After that you can check the same way for RGB or CMYK.

Comment: 大変ありがとうございます。非常に参考になります。回答のほうではRGBAでの値となっておりますが、グレースケールでは何かしら違うものが必要なのでしょうか。質問ばかり、申し訳ありません。

Comment: ご回答のほどありがとうございます。
CGColorGetNumberOfComponentsというメソッドで、グレースケールの色かどうかを判別できます。
グレースケールの色ではこの値が２となり、輝度(0.0が黒、1.0が白）とα値が取得できます。
グレースケール以外の色ではこの値が４となり、RGBの各値とα値が取得できます。
ということが書いてありますところが見つかりました。このような質問にも回答していただきましてありがとうございました。